# How to write the dual

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, duality-theorems, integer-programming

So I do not have any problems writing the dual of the primal if I work with numerical examples, but however I am stuck on writing the dual of the shortest-path problem when it is written in a more "formal" way:

\begin{align*}
&\text{minimize} & \sum_{(i,j) \in A} c_{ij} x_{ij}\\
&\text{subject to} & \sum_{k \in V^{+}(i)} x_{ik} - \sum_{k \in V^{-}(i)}x_{ki} &= \begin{cases}
1 &\text{for $i=s$}\\
0 &\text{for $i \in V\setminus\{s,t\}$}\\
-1 &\text{for $i=t$ }
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

My book says this is the dual:

\begin{align*}
&\text{maximize} & \pi_t - \pi_s\\
&\text{subject to} & \pi_j - \pi_i &\leq c_{ij} &&\text{for $(i,j)\in A$} \\
\end{align*}

However I do not understand this suggestion. So for every constraint in the primal we have one variable in the dual. Hence $\pi_s, \pi_i$ and $\pi_t$. This is at least what I am taught. There is only one variable in the primal, $x_{ij}$, if I am not mistanken. So there will only be one constraint in the primal, so I understand so far. I do however not understand how to obtain the constraint given in the dual. Why $\pi_j - \pi_i \leq c_{ij}$ ? More specifically, how do I obtain the left side of that inequality and why do we have a new varible $\pi_j$ as it is only three constraints in the primal, not four? I know there is a similiar question here on stackexchange, but I did not understand the answers properly. I would really appreciate some help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your formulations for better clarity.

There are $|A|$ primal variables $x_{ij}$ and $|V|$ primal constraints (one per $i$).  So there are $|A|$ dual constraints (one per $(i,j)$) and $|V|$ dual variables $\pi_i$.

Arthur Benjamin's [S-O-B method](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2132755.pdf?casa_token=7JzPfqmqY6AAAAAA:sJoHGZEP-sqRN1MbchgfPgRkh38BLR39x03y2L_rRZBpLSq1D_Jm06WLGnl1fxhhtd45g1wa3qJOHn1Ef5Q04Y6Nm6kfk6LYc5kljI5SaNLBTyVSDu66) is useful for obtaining the dual LP.